# Whitespace lost with XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform a Xml with a Xslt. But the whitespace between 2 words is lost when using the C# code. For example between the words "VOLKOREN" and "HAVERVLOKKEN"
When using the Visual Studio Xslt debugger, the output is fine.
How can I get the same output using C# code?

**C#**

```
            XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument();
            source.LoadXml(Resources.ResourceFile.source);

            XmlDocument stylesheet = new XmlDocument();
            stylesheet.LoadXml(Resources.ResourceFile.stylesheet);

            XmlDocument doc = null;
            XslCompiledTransform xct = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
            XsltSettings xs = new XsltSettings(true, true);
            xct.Load(stylesheet, xs, new XmlUrlResolver());
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
            using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
            {
                xct.Transform(source, null, writer);
            }
```

**Xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl xhtml" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
      <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Xml" mode="languagecode_element_ingredientstatement_xhtml"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="output">
        <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$output"/>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:*" mode="languagecode_element_ingredientstatement_xhtml">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="languagecode_element_ingredientstatement_xhtml"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:strong" mode="languagecode_element_ingredientstatement_xhtml">
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $lowercase, $uppercase)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="languagecode_element_ingredientstatement_xhtml">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Xml**

```
<Xml>
  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <strong>Volkoren</strong> <strong>havervlokken</strong>, <strong>Volkoren</strong> <strong>gerstvlokken</strong>, <strong>Volkoren</strong> <strong>speltvlokken</strong>, zonnebloempitten (9%), plantaardige vezels, lijnzaad (6%), pompoenpitten (5%), meloenpitten (3%). Kan sporen van pinda's, noten en soja bevatten.
  </p>
</Xml>
```

**Exptected ouput**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Output>

    VOLKOREN HAVERVLOKKEN, VOLKOREN GERSTVLOKKEN, VOLKOREN SPELTVLOKKEN, zonnebloempitten (9%), plantaardige vezels, lijnzaad (6%), pompoenpitten (5%), meloenpitten (3%). Kan sporen van pinda's, noten en soja bevatten.

</Output>
```

**Output with C# code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Output>VOLKORENHAVERVLOKKEN, VOLKORENGERSTVLOKKEN, VOLKORENSPELTVLOKKEN, zonnebloempitten (9%), plantaardige vezels, lijnzaad (6%), pompoenpitten (5%), meloenpitten (3%). Kan sporen van pinda's, noten en soja bevatten.
  </Output>
```

Comment: Doesn't `XmlDocument` have a `PreserveWhitespace` or similar property you can set before the `LoadXml`?

Comment: I just tested this. Replace `XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument();` with `XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};`